# Can you add import random numbers together?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import random
for i in range(0,6):
    sum1=(random.randint(0,6))
    print(sum1)
```

number it prints out:

```
6
6
5
1
6
1
```

could you add the random numbers above(6+6+5+1+6+1=25)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: `sum(random.randint(0, 6) for _ in range(6))`? Note that `randint(0, 6)` potentially includes `0`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: The 6 is for the 6 balls it takes to get  an over in cricket and the (random.randint(0,6) is the score while the other 6 is theamount of balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```
import random
sum1 = 0
for i in range(0,6):
    sum1 += (random.randint(0,6))
print(sum1)
```

Add one - liner for this solution is:

```
import random
print(sum(random.sample(xrange(7), 6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
import random
sum1=0
for i in range(0,6):
    sum1+=random.randint(0,6)
print(sum1)
```

And a one liner for this would be

```
print sum( random.randint(0,6) for i in range(0,6) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

all_sum = 0
for i in range(0,6):
    sum1=(random.randint(0,6))
    all_sum += sum1

print all_sum
```

The result should be summation of those six random number.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need this?

```
import random
sum1 = sum([random.randint(0, 6) for i in range(6)])
```